# How to create a wordcloud for a phrase not individual word in python

Tags: python, word-cloud

I'm trying to create wordcloud from a list that each name is a phrase but at final result each part shows separately and need to keep them as one element at wordcloud

after I plot this data frame each part of the word placed separately at the picture.
How to keep each value together?`

```
df=['Jurassic park','Captain America','Universal Studios','Mad max']

text=df
title = WordCloud(width=1000,             height=500,background_color="white",max_words=10).generate(text)
plt.axis("off")
plt.imshow(title)
plt.show()
```

`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a for loop to look through each item and do whatever you need to with the length of the words.

```
df=['Jurassic park','Captain America','Universal Studios','Mad max']

for name in df:
    print(len(name))
```